# Mongoose + TypeScript: Conditionally find() documents on model throws error: Union type has signatures, but none are compatible with each other

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to conditionally access a mongoose model in my TypeScript code. Anyone knows how to fix this TypeScript error?
`Each member of the union type has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other`

`.find()` on the conditional model throws the error.

```
interface PictureDocument extends Document {
    paint: string;
}
interface VideoDocument extends Document {
    duration: number;
}

const PictureSchema = new Schema<PictureDocument>({ paint: String });
const VideoSchema = new Schema<VideoDocument>({ duration: Number });

const PictureModel = model<PictureDocument>("video", PictureSchema);
const VideoModel = model<VideoDocument>("video", VideoSchema);

const MY_CONDITION = "picture";

const getDocuments = async (condition: "picture" | "video") => {
    const model = condition === "picture" ? PictureModel : VideoModel; // <--- Here I conditionally get my model to execute queries on

    return await model.find().exec(); // <--- .find() throws TS error here
};

getDocuments(MY_CONDITION);
```

```
This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '{ (callback?: ((err: any, res: VideoDocument[]) => void) | undefined): DocumentQuery<VideoDocument[], VideoDocument, {}>; (conditions: FilterQuery<...>, callback?: ((err: any, res: VideoDocument[]) => void) | undefined): DocumentQuery<...>; (conditions: FilterQuery<...>, projection?: any, callback?: ((err: any, res:...' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay actually it was quite simple and it is a common solution to union type problems in TypeScript I think

```
const model: Model<PictureDocument | VideoDocument> = condition === "picture" ? PictureModel : VideoModel;
```

By adding the type to the variable declaration, the union type problem is solved.